# Ajax Uploading with Symfony's HTTP Foundation

Tags: ajax, symfony

I used symfony's HTTTP foundation as a part of my own project. But I can't found the way for ajax uploading with it.

**How to upload file in Symfony's HTTP Foundation with ajax?** Is there any plugin or addons or another way?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a component like jQuery Upload, Uploadify, etc... You might only have any trouble with the uploading process described in here (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) if you are doing it behind a firewall (restrict area, e.g.).

The whole problem is that the session id (usually stored in cookie) is not present with those uploading component requests. It's do a Flash's limitation. Use the procedure described in this article ( http://www.elao.com/blog/symfony-2/symfony-2-loading-session-from-query-param.html ) and you should be fine.